# dynamic window.find not working with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I can't for the life of me figure out why this isn't working.

I want to search the current page for text using a search box. I googled and found this: http://www.javascripter.net/faq/searchin.htm . I implemented the code into my site, but it doesn't work. the function ( `findString()` ) works, but only when I hard-code a string (as in i can't use javascript or jquery to get the value of a text input). I made this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/alyda/CPJrh/4/ to illustrate the problem.

You can uncomment different lines to see what I've tested.

Comment: Why can't you use javascript or jquery to get the value of a text input?

Comment: it's simply not working with the function. I can trace the value I want using either jquery or vanilla javascript, but its just not working with the function provided.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery has a method [**:contains()**](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) that will make easier what you are looking for.

Take a look here: [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/JKZ9T/)

```
$("button[type='submit']").click(function () {
    var string = $('#search').val();
    var matched = $('li:contains(' + string + ')');
    matched.css('color','red');
    console.log(matched);
    return false;
});
```

Comment: My intent is to use only the browser's search function, rather than custom text highlighting. Silly me, I thought somehow that would be easier...

Answer (score 0):

In firefox I noticed that the fiddle (v4) as given in the question worked, but not in the way the asker expected it to.

What happens in firefox is that the function *does* find the value..: you have just entered it in the input-field. Then the browser's `find` method seems to hang in the 'context' of the input 'control' and doesn't break out of it. Since the browser will continue to search from the last active position, if you select anything after the input-field, the function works as expected. So the trick is not to get 'trapped' in the input-field at the start of your search.

A basic (dirty) example on how to break out of it (not necessarily the proper solution nor pure jquery, but might inspire a useful routine, since you now know the root of the problem in FF):

```
$( "button[type='submit']" ).click(function(){

    var tst=$('#search').val(); //close over value
    $('#search').val('');       //clear input
    if(tst){                    //sanity check
      this.nextSibling.onclick=function(){findString( tst );}; //example how to proceed
      findString( tst );  //find first value
    } else { alert('please enter something to search for'); }
    return false;
});
```

[Example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CPJrh/7/) is tested (working) in FF.

PS: given your specific example using `<li>`, I do feel Sergio's answer would be a more appropriate *solution*, especially since that would never run line: `alert ("Opera browsers not supported, sorry...")`, but the proper *answer* to your `window.find` question is still an interesting one!

PS2: if you essentially are using (or replicating) the browser's search-function, why not *[educate](http://www.theatlantic.com/technology/archive/2011/08/crazy-90-percent-of-people-dont-know-how-to-use-ctrl-f/243840/)* the user and instruct them to hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>?

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm aware that the browser search function will also match the input, I'm not too worried about that. But if you look at the code, it will continue to find additional matches (If you keep pressing submit, which is not extremely user-friendly, but I was trying to avoid custom text-highlighting).

Comment: RE: PS2, I thought perhaps I would be educating the user if they noticed the find window opening when they pressed submit (or that their interaction with the search on that page matched the interaction if they had simply pressed CTRL+F). I'm afraid the typical user for this website may not be inclined to learning such a simple but useful command, either they have already figured it out on their own, or they simply don't care.

Comment: added check on empty submit and added the rest of the explanation I gave in a (now deleted) comment to your question (but forgot to copy to this answer).

Answer (score 0):

I found a fix (sort of). It seems that the input needs to be placed well AFTER the content to be searched in the DOM. That means I've done the following:

```
<section class="content">
  <h2>Fire</h2>
  <h3>Fire Extinguishers</h3>
  <ul>
    <li>Model 240</li>
    <li>Model C352, C352TS</li>
<li>Model C354, C354TS</li>
  </ul>
  ...
  <div id="navbar">
    <ul>
      ...
    </ul>
    <input id="search" type="text" class="form-control pull-left" placeholder="Search for part number">
    <button id="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-default pull-left" style=" margin-top:6px;">Search</button>
  </div>
```

as you can see, I've moved the input (which is in the navbar div) BELOW all of the text I want to search, and used CSS to programmatically place the navbar at the top of the page. I don't particularly like this setup (as it messes with the flow of content) but since I was looking for the quickest and simplest implementation of a single-page search, it will have to do.

I would still love to know why this happens, when the javascript is at the end of the DOM where it belongs...

Comment: simple, as explained in my answer. The native find searches top (last known position) to bottom. Your solution is to get trapped in the inputfield at the end of the search (bottom) instead of right away at the start (top).

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem in an angularjs app and I fix it by changing DOM structure.
my HTML code was something like this:

```
<body>
       <div class="content" >
            <input class="searchInput" />
            <p>
                content ....
            </p>
       </div>
</body>
```

and I changed it to something like this:

```
<body>
       <div class="search">
            <input class="searchInput" />
       </div>

       <div class="content">
            <p>
                content ....
            </p>
       </div>
</body>
```

> Note: I'm aware that this topic is old.